# Python3 can't find brew installed module

Tags: python, python-3.x, homebrew

I have installed python using brew as: `brew install python`
Then I have installed required library (re2) as `brew install re2`, that have been installed successfully, but when I run `import re2` in python or trying to install a library, that has re2 dependency, via pip, it throws an error that there is no such library. 
May be I should add some link or what may be the reason of the error?

Comment: post your error

Comment: What is your default python version? how did you install re2 ? type python --version to find out the version

Comment: pip install *** is for python2 and pip3 install *** is for python3. did u install in correct version ?

Comment: `python --version` -> `Python 3.7.4`